# promise returns undefined while calling from two different mysql queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

I Have two mysql queries that runs with promise.

The first one is updates information on a mysql table and then resolves the issue and calls the next mysql query. The problem is that, when it calls the next mysql query the promise returns UNDEFINED and I am not sure why. When I console.log it out in my node js server post request, it gives undefined. I documented on the code which areas are problems.

```
UpdateUserPath = (data) => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    data.UPDATE_DT = getDateTime();
    db.query('UPDATE path  UPDATE_DT = ?  where Owner = ?',
        [data.UPDATE_DT, data.Owner], function(err,results,fields){
        if(err){
            reject('Could not update user path');
        }else{
            if(results.affectedRows > 0){
                data.ID = null;
                data.UPDATE_DT = null;
                // The problem is here, when this gets resolved it calls the other function SaveUserPath
                resolve(saveUserPath(data));
            }else{
                reject('Could not update user path');
            }
        }
    });
});


saveUserPath = (data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query('INSERT INTO path SET ?', data, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            reject('Could not insert path');
        }else{
            var Id = results.insertId;

            db.query('UPDATE path SET ORIG_ID = ? where ID = ?',[Id, Id], function(err,results,fields){
                if(err){
                    reject('Could not insert row to path  table - saveuserpath');
                }else{
                    if(results.affectedRows > 0){
                       // THIS INFORMATION HERE IS UNDEFINED
                        return resolve(results[0]);
                    }else{
                        reject('Could not update path');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In the server it gets called like this.

```
getUserPath(req.session.userid).then((path_data)=>{
                path_data.status = 1;
                UpdateUserPath(path_data).then((result)=>{
                    console.log(result); // THIS IS UNDEFINED
                });
            });
```

I am wondering if `resolve(saveUserPath(data));` is the right way to call another promise which is not outside in the server. 
I was thinking of just doing it this way.

```
UpdateUserPath(path_data).then((result)=>{
   saveUserPath(result).then((result_save) => {
     console.log(result_save); // THIS MIGHT WORK 
   });
});
```

But why is the normal way wrong.

Comment: In `saveUserPath()`, what does `console.log(results)` for the second query show?

Comment: This is a class example of how you should use the promisified interface for your database directly rather than try to wrap multiple nested callbacks in a manually created promise.  This code is way more error prone and verbose than it needs to be.

Comment: @jfriend00 that works normally.

Comment: @jfriend00 any suggestion to fix, I am not quite sure what you meant.

Comment: `// THIS INFORMATION HERE IS UNDEFINED` - so, if you `console.log(results[0])` at that exact line, you get `undefined` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several guesses why it isn't working, but there are a number of things wrong such that it's better to just clean up the code to a much better design.

When combining multiple asynchronous callback-driven operations in an otherwise promise-based interface, you really want to promisify the underlying functions at their lowest level and then you can implement all your control flow and error handling using the benefits of promises.  I think that will also make your problem go away and probably fix a couple other bugs too.

```
// promisify db.query()
// if a promisified interface is built into your database, use that one instead
db.queryP = function(q, d) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
        db.query(q, d, (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
}

UpdateUserPath = function(data) {
    data.UPDATE_DT = getDateTime();
    let q = 'UPDATE path  UPDATE_DT = ?  where Owner = ?';
    return db.queryP(q, [data.UPDATE_DT, data.Owner]).then(results => {
        if (results.affectedRows > 0) {
            data.ID = null;
            data.UPDATE_DT = null;
            return saveUserPath(data);
        } else {
            throw new Error('Could not update user path');
        }
    });
}

saveUserPath = function(data) {
    let q = 'INSERT INTO path SET ?'
    return db.queryP(q, data).then(results => {
        let q2 = 'UPDATE path SET ORIG_ID = ? where ID = ?';
        var Id = results.insertId;
        return db.queryP(q2, [Id, Id]).then(results2 => {
            if (results2.affectedRows > 0) {
                return results2[0];
            } else {
                throw new Error('Could not update path');
            }
        });
    });
}

getUserPath(req.session.userid).then(path_data => {
    path_data.status = 1;
    return UpdateUserPath(path_data);
}).then(result => {
    // process result here
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
});
```

Comment: I was thinking the same think about the resolve part. But yea, rewriting might be a better idea, can I please keep this question open for a while to see what else people might come up with, if there is nothing else I will just rewrite it and give you the award :D Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @FarhanaFayez - certainly you can wait a bit for other answers before accepting one as the best answer, but if this is helpful, you can upvote all helpful answers at any time.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - If you're talking about in the OP's code, that won't work.  It's inside a promise executor function and inside an async callback so returning a promise doesn't do anything there.  If you're talking about in my code, then that's what I already do.

Comment: @jfriend00, it's a comment on your footnote. Have you run a test?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `resolve(saveUserPath(data));` should be cool.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - Nope, didn't think it worth the effort since I'd already rewritten it in a better way that doesn't have that issue.  I removed that footnote from my answer.